# Simple ASP.NET MVC Mobile App Sync with Server once back Online

Tags: jquery, mobile, synchronization

Ok I want to create a simple app that lets users add things to a list on their phone.

However I want it to store in local storage if offline, then once back online post all the things to the server that have not yet been synced.

What is the most simple way to go about this?  I would use jQuery/mobile and would mostly be used on an iPhone.

Would I need to setup a setTimout in order to constantly check for online connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

If a command fails due to the lack of connection switch to offline mode. When in offline mode periodically check whether you have a connection with setTimeout. If the connection is restored, don't check for connection periodically.